# ORA-22992 Remove references to LOB in remote table issue

Tags: oracle, casting, subquery, sql-insert, lob

I am trying to insert into table CAPTURED_DATA_01 with multiple select statement.I am able to insert the value EVENT_ID,ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID but now i also want to insert the SUBSCRIPTION_ID value which is coming i will get from using the select statement in remote table. The query i have tested and runs fine for getting the SUBSCRIPTION_ID. But when i try to use this select statement in order to insert the value of SUBSCRIPTION_ID into inside my insert query then i am getting the error where i have used cast function  for the SUBSCRIPTION_ID inside my subquery as

```
SQL Error: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
22992. 00000 -  "cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
*Cause:    A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
*Action:   Remove references to LOBs in remote tables
```

Here is my Query:

```
Insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) 
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
   from 
   (select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF,CAPTURED_DATA_01 CP
where WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID > CP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID and 
WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IN
( 
select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from (
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) 
   AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
   CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML, '<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'),
    '<ns7:orderType>', ''), '</ns7:orderType>', '')
  AS VARCHAR(100)) AS order_type,
  TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber> '), 
   '<ax2147:orderNumber>', ''), '</ax2147:orderNumber> ', '')) 
   AS ORDER_NUMBER,
   CREATE_DATE
   FROM
   SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL 
   where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
) iw
where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION'
)and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0)
```

Comment: There is only a small problem with this statement TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>') where i am getting the error :( and there is no documention available to search for this error.
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) 
   AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID

Comment: I think the problem is that the insert is always processed locally, so it doesn't do the substr etc. on the LOB columns remotely as it can with a plain select. You can change the behaviour with the driving_site hint (to break that) but the hint is ignored for insert as far as I'm aware. You may need to query in a cursor in a PL/SQL block and (bulk) insert from that.

Comment: ohh ok i am quiet poor in PL/SQL but try with some cursor then in this case. Do u have any cursor example for this select query ?

Comment: Cant we use Merge statement in this case ?

Comment: If you have a key field(s) you can use for the the `on` then yes. Added that to my answer. You might want to compare the performance of both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the problem is that an `insert` is always run on the local database.

When you just run the `select` on its own Oracle can decide (or be hinted) to do some of the work on the remote database; in this case it's transforming the CLOB values into number and varchar2 types, and only those non-LOB values have to be transmitted across the network to your local database for further processing.

For the insert it will try to retrieve the whole LOB to transform it locally, and it stops that from happening - presumably due to the potential amount of data involved. The `driving_site` hint is ignored for an insert so you can't tweak that behaviour as you can for a select.

To work around it you can do the select and insert as two steps, via a cursor in a PL/SQL block. The general pattern would be:

```
declare
  type cp_tab_type is table of CAPTURED_DATA_01%ROWTYPE;
  cp_tab cp_tab_type;
  cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open cur for
    select ... -- some value for every column in the table you're inserting
               -- into, in the same order they appear in the DDL
  loop
    fetch cur bulk collect into cp_tab;
    exit when cp_tab.count = 0;
    forall i in 1..cp_tab.count
      insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01 values cp_tab(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

[Read more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) about bulk collect and forall to do batch query/inserts.

You could also, as you suggested, use a `merge` if you have something you can use for the `on` clause; for exmaple if `event-id` was not going to exist at all yet:

```
merge into CAPTURED_DATA_01 cp
using (
    select ..
) data
on (cp.event_id = data.event_id)
when not matched then
insert (EVENT_ID,SUBSCRIPTION_ID,EVENT_TIMESTAMP,ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID)
values (data.event_id, data.subscription_id, data.start_date,
  data.env_id, data.brand_id, data.bp_id);
```

Your query gets more complicated with each question you post and could probably be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: Hello Alex thanks for your hint. What do u think with the Merge is it possible to insert remotely ? or i will face the same issue like normal insert ? So that instead of working on completetd bulk insert using cursor ,i could give a try with the Merge ?

Comment: I edited a question by removing other columns And i want to give a try with the merge by simply inserting SUBSCRIPTION_ID excluding other columns first so in this case you know how the Merge statement looks like as per my question ?

Comment: To only use one column, just change the insert and values clauses. Where did the remote insert come from? It's very frustrating when you keep changing the requirements, restriction and existing code. Good luck.

Comment: No Alex i did not change the requirement. Instead of inserting other values in column, i am just trying to insert the SUBSCRIPTION_ID first into CAPTURED_ID_01 table. Because this is important for me. If it works then the other column values i can insert locally as i am running this query locally.

Comment: Hello Alex it works with the Merge statement. Thank you :). Just a last question. I tried to insert for SUBSCRIPTION_ID,EVENT_TIMESTAMP,EVENT_ID and it was inserting the value. But i have added more columns now ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID and its showing small error. Here is my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323869/merge-insert-into-using-multiple-select-statement-issue